# ClientSide RowSelect stops working after pagesize change in radgrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have many telerik rad grids in my project . 
It initialize with ability to have client side row selection with

```
<clientsettings>
      <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
</clientsettings>
```

it is ok and in first load when my paging selector is on 10 object per grid selecting works fine , but when I change page size to 20 or 50 selecting suddenly stops working and I can not select row as before . Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

> RadGrid loses its current selection on postback - e.g. when the data is sorted, a new
>   group or filter is added, or when the current page changes.

You can try following approaches to implement a way to persist the client-side selection. (sample code snippet is in the attached link)

- [Using Web Storage](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/selecting/how-to/persisting-selected-rows-client-side#using-web-storage)
- [Using JavaScript array](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/selecting/how-to/persisting-selected-rows-client-side#using-web-storage)

> The following logic is used to persist the selected rows:
>
> 1. Handle `OnRowSelected` and `OnRowDeselected` events for RadGrid. In the handlers you should update the collection of the selected items.
> 2. Handle `OnRowCreated` event. In this handler you should check if the current item is present in the selected rows collection and select
>      it if necessary.

For full details, please check this article - [Persisting the Selected Rows Client-side on Sorting/Paging/Filtering/Grouping](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/selecting/how-to/persisting-selected-rows-client-side#persisting-the-selected-rows-client-side-on-sortingpagingfilteringgrouping)